# Time and Space Complexity of Leetcode Problem #31. Next Permutation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, combinatorics, complexity, backtracking

The question is as follows: Given a collection of distinct integers, return all possible permutations. Example:

```
Input: [1,2,3]
Output:
[
  [1,2,3],
  [1,3,2],
  [2,1,3],
  [2,3,1],
  [3,1,2],
  [3,2,1]
]
```

Here is my backtracking solution for the problem, where I added the `num_calls` variable to keep track of the number of times that the `backtrack` function is called recursively.

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums):
        answer = []
        num_calls = []

        def backtrack(combo, rem):
            if len(rem) == 0:
                answer.append(combo)
            for i in range(len(rem)):
                num_calls.append(1)
                backtrack(combo + [rem[i]], rem[:i] + rem[i + 1:])

        if len(nums) == 0:
            return None
        backtrack([], nums)
        print(len(num_calls))
        return answer
```

I can't make sense of any of the answers that I have seen thus far for the time and space complexity of this solution.

Some people say its worst case O(n * n!), but looking at the len of `num_calls` doesn't verify this claim.

For example, for:

```
test = Solution()
print(test.permute([1, 2, 3]))
```

length of num_calls = 15, which != n * n! = 3 * (3*2*1) = 18

, for:

```
test = Solution()
print(test.permute([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

length of num_calls = 64, which != n * n! = 4 * (4*3*2*1) = 96.

, and for:

```
test = Solution()
print(test.permute([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

length of num_calls = 325, which != n * n! = 5 * (5*4*3*2*1) = 600

Can someone please explain this in a simplified and easily understandable manner?

Answer (score 1):

The number of calls indeed grows slower than \$n*n!\$. Its growth is only \$O(n!)\$. However, number of calls is not the only source of complexity.

Constructing arguments for the recursive call also takes time, and `rem[:i] + rem[i + 1:]` is on average linear in terms of `n`. The total complexity therefore is \$O(n*n!)\$, just as some people say.

Comment: How is the growth of the number of calls only O(n!)? For each of the examples I showed above, the number of calls is greater than n!. In addition, could you explain a bit more as to why `rem[:i] + rem[i + 1:]` is on average linear?